# How can I tell if a check has been deposited?

Tags: check, deposits

I found an old check in my drawer from two months ago and I can't remember whether or not I cashed it. I typically use digital deposit and don't usually void my checks when I've finished.

I'm not able to check the amount on my transaction history, as I have multiple checks listed with the same amount. I don't want to try depositing the check, as I'm worried I may be charged a fee.

**How can I find out if I've already deposited a check?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use online banking, you can go back to the time in question, and *view* the images of all checks with that amount. Even if you have four of five with the same, it takes only a minute to view all images.

In addition, if it is not signed, you probably didn't deposit it. If it is signed, you probably did.

Comment: I can't tell you how because I'm not a customer of them, but if you google 'capital one view check images', the first match shows instructions.

Comment: I urge you to contact your bank if necessary to learn how to view the deposit image. Such images are useful for proving that you are not at fault for any issues with cashing a check. Recently, I deposited a check via nt bank's mobile app. My bank subsequently withdrew the funds and charged me a return fee because they claimed the account on the check did not exist. The problem, discovered immediately after looking at the check image, was that their mobile app took a perfectly clear image of the check, *except* for inexplicably blurring the last few digits of the account number.

Answer (score 0):

You could call the bank and ask if there's a deposit for the amount of the check. If there is, then you could confirm the bank the check was from, which should clear things up.

Answer (score 0):

There are four ways that I can tell if a check has been deposited.

1. I don't sign the back of the check until I am ready to scan the check.
2. The scan of the check is in a specific folder on my computer.
3. My credit union provides a receipt page that they suggest that you print. I print it to a pdf file. The receipt page has the check image.
4. The email confirmation.

Some of these methods may not help you, but they might give you an idea of where to look.

There is also a fifth option. Some checks now come with a checkbox on the back. They suggest you check the box when you deposit the check.

Comment: Many banks don't allow prior scans to be used for security, but only use the camera directly from their app. So you don't get a file (unless you make one separately)